# ASP.NET Web API with Windows Authentication lacks header WWW-Authenticate in response

Tags: asp.net, security

I understand that, for a secured request, a client does an anonymous request first, gets a 401 response and a WWW-Authenticate header and then retries using the received Authentication system.

Now, I have the following code: (if something is missing, let me know)

web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
</system.web>
```

Controller.cs:

```
[Authorize]
public class FunctionalLocationsController : ApiController
{
  // ..
}
```

WebApiConfig:

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")
{
    SupportsCredentials = true
});
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Request (fiddler):

```
GET http://localhost/MADI.Backend.WebApi/api/functionallocations HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 04 Jan 2019 13:44:17 GMT
Content-Length: 6084
```

The response also contains the human message in Html about the 401.

Does anybody know why it is NOT returning the WWW-Authenticate header?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh... I found it myself 10 minutes after posting here...

Windows Integrated Security is something you need to explicitly enable in your Windows Features.

I figured `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` enabled it, but that's only the case when it is also installed. Else it silently does nothing (to my knowledge).

it works now.